# Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation

Tags: ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, ios5.1

I am building a ipad application. when the applications starts i show it in landscape Right mode. But as soon as the application starts I get this message

```
Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation
```

I used this method in all my classes

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

I also set my supported interface orientations (iPad) to landscape right in my plist file.
How to resolve this warning message?

Comment: If you try to use modal UITabBarController(upd. Yes you do), then see solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271978/presenting-uitabbarcontroller-modally-autorotate-problem). Official explanation why this happend [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636683/how-to-eliminate-two-stage-rotation-warning).

Comment: @Alexander I do not show the tabbar modally.

Comment: Is you "Login screen" a NavigationController? All controllers,that must be "rootViewController",shouldn't be used as "modal".

Comment: @Alexander LoginScreen is a shown as a modal to tabbar controller. All other controllers added to tabbar controller are under navigation controller as rootViewControllers. On login i dismiss the login modal to show the tabbars

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just realized - after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636683/how-to-eliminate-two-stage-rotation-warning) answer - that I was simply using the Tab Bar Controller wrong: the tab bar should only be used as a root controller, however I inserted a navigation controller before it.

Comment: It seems tab bar controller could be used in nav controller in iOS8 but get the error in iOS7.

Answer (score 7):

You can also get this error message if you've run the app with an empty tab bar controller as root in your storyboard. I was just starting on an app and my `UITabBarController` has no view controllers yet, but is presenting a login modal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your app is using one of these methods, which were deprecated in iOS 5.0:

```
didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

You need to modify your view controllers to override `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` instead, and to *not* override any of the "HalfOfRotation" methods.

Comment: Where do i place this method.

Comment: what my app exactly does is-I have a tabbar application. I init a tabbarcontroller in my appdelegate and add all my classes to the array of tabbarcontroller. Then i add a login screen in the front of the tabbar and after login i show the tabbar. My application opens in the landscape mode, but i get this warning. also I think because of this i am getting my keyboard size incorrect. on displaying the keyboard width and height in landscape mode it gives me width = 352 and height =1024 in ipad 3. I seems that the system does not know that it is currently in landscape mode. Thanks

Comment: Did you search all your source code for those deprecated methods?

Comment: Yes. Actually these methods do not appear anywhere in my code.

Comment: Since 6.0 at least willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: also triggers this ... sometimes, i have two projects with just willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: nothing else, one yields the notice, other doesn't, there must be cruft in the nib's causing it.

Comment: @valexa Thanks for the info..Appreciate it.

Comment: I just had this message appear for the first time after adding a UINavigationController to a Storyboard that previously didn't have one.  I was targeting iOS 5.1 ... the message disappears once I changed deployment to target iOS 6.0.

Comment: @brindy Still havent moved to iOS 6.0. Once done i shall update this...Thanks

Comment: Experienced the same as Brindy, targeting 7.0 on Xcode5 - except changing deployment target isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

ckeck your array declaration for tab bar
..possible mistake u done:
  I declared array oblects after assigning

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = tabControlArry;
[tabControlArry addObject:navCOntroller];
[tabControlArry addObject:navController1];
```

correct way:

```
[tabControlArry addObject:navCOntroller];
[tabControlArry addObject:navController1];
tabBarController.viewControllers = tabControlArry;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is related to TabBarController usage. You can expect this error when you don't make your tabBarController as the **"root controller"** for your app. So make your TabBarController as the root controller & this error will no more pester you.