# UITabBarController. Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated.

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, facebook-authentication

I implemented Facebook auth using the official fb ios sdk guide. I have modified the code to use Storyboards instead of .nibs and it's working correctly with two view controllers, login view controller and the main view controller, however I'm trying to use a TabBarController as the main view controller and it's working properly but there is a warning: "Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation.
"

Any idea how to get rid of this warning?

The code for set the rootViewController is the following:

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                              bundle:nil];
self.mainViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UITabBarController"]; // Identifier

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                      initWithRootViewController:self.mainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Someone has already answered this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027764/two-stage-rotation-animation-is-deprecated-this-application-should-use-the-smoo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027764/two-stage-rotation-animation-is-deprecated-this-application-should-use-the-smoo) tl;dr Don't use a navigation controller with a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are being warned because you are not supposed to use a Tab Bar within a Navigation Controller.  The Tab Bar controller should be your root controller, otherwise use something other than a tab bar in its place.

There are [plenty of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6637554/793607) talking about this.